# Syntax for rails g migration with Space

Tags: rails-generate

hello.

I'm trying to add a column called `product_size` to my `order_items` table in my schema.

Do I do this by:

`$ rails g migration add_product_size_to_order_items`

or

`$ rails g migration add_product_size_to_OrderItem`

or otherwise?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
rails g migration add_product_size_to_order_items
```

then add also this line `product_size:data_type`

**sample:**

```
rails g migration add_product_size_to_order_items product_size:decimal
```

Comment: Thanks!  :)  It worked:

```$ rails g migration add_product_size_to_order_items product_size:string```